# Can I fly from Spain to UK with an Irish certificate of citizenship and a Bolivian passport?

Tags: spain, ireland

My son will have an Irish Certificate of Citizenship within the next few weeks, hopefully. We're hoping to go to Northern Ireland at the end of the year, and it seems unlikely we'll have time to get him an Irish passport before that. For Ireland, that's not an issue since he has a Bolivian passport, which is visa free there. But, we'll likely have to travel through Spain. As a citizen, will he be able to get a Schengen visa? Or can we travel on his Bolivian passport with the certificate of citizenship? It's a complicated situation.

Comment: Where are you traveling from?  Are you flying directly to Northern Ireland or will you land in the Republic of Ireland and make your way to Northern Ireland by land?

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Will you stay in Spain or in any way need to go through passport control in Spain (due to separate tickets for Bolivia-Spain and Spain-Ireland for instance)? If both flights are on the same ticket you usually don’t need a visa for Spain. Also note that Bolivian citizens have visa-free access to the Republic of Ireland but not to Northern Ireland which is part of the UK.

Comment: @jcaron As an Irish citizen the OP’s son can exercise his Common Travel Area rights to enter N Ireland (and the rest of the UK). https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/government_in_ireland/ireland_and_the_uk/common_travel_area_between_ireland_and_the_uk.html

Comment: @Traveller the common travel area is more an effect of Irish citizens' rights in the UK than their source, but otherwise that is correct.

Comment: @Traveller Yes, but that requires the certificate of citizenship to be accepted, which may be the case within the CTA, but I doubt an airline would accept that for boarding a flight to the UK (or even to Ireland).

Comment: @jcaron Agreed. Entering NI depends on the OP’s son being able to reach Ireland. So eg Spain > Dublin and overland to NI works, but Spain > London > NI by air does not.

Answer (score 2):

You can't fly to the UK directly as British authorities will [only accept](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/before-you-leave-for-the-uk) a valid Irish passport or passport card for entry from outside the Common Travel Area. However you could fly to Dublin, enter as an Irish citizen and then drive or take the bus to Northern Ireland. Its perfectly legal for Irish citizens to cross the land border even if they don't have any documents at all, thanks to the Common Travel Area.